# What is the simplest approach to execute a Swift statement only after an asynchronous operation finishes (pre-Swift 5.5)?

Tags: ios, swift

For example,

- Operation A both fetches model data over the network and updates a `UICollectionView` backed by it.
- Operation B filters model data.

What is a good approach to executing B only after A is finished?

Comment: [Meet async/await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132)

Comment: In a pre-Swift 5.5 project, I'll update the question.

Comment: The video addresses that as well. There are a few mentions on how was done

Comment: Dispatch Group is your friend

Comment: Instead of waving vague terms around please say _exactly_ what the task is. Is it: download data, _then_ update interface, _then_ filter data? Is there some reason why the filtering has to wait like that?

Answer (score 0):

**Closure** is the simplest answer to your needs. It is the most traditional and the simplest way of handling asynchronous operation in iOS development.

Here is a sample code:

```
func operationA(number : Int, completion: (Bool)->()) {
    //fetch data
    //update collectionview
    //completion closure is our opetion B
    completeion(true) //invoke operation B
}

operationA(number: 2) { (result) -> () in
    //perform operation B
}
```

You could read more about closures [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

**PS:** Although `Closure` might be the **simplest** solution, I would highly recommend seeking **better** solutions (not simplest) such as [Reactive Programming in Swift called `RxSwift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) or [Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html) in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You could Use the `Combine` framework and have multiple sinks on the returned data. The first updates the collection view, the second performs the filter and updates the table view:

```swift
func fetchAndFilter() {
let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(...)
    .share() // -> turns this into a multicast publisher

let fetchCancellable = publisher
    .sink { // Update your collection view with the publisher's output }

let filterCancellable = publisher
    .sink { // filter publisher's output and update the collection View }

// store the cancellables appropriately.

}
```

Both sinks receive the data as it is published.